Android: Activity animation not playing when clicking on notification
In my MyFirebaseMessagingService, I create a notification (even when the app is currently in foreground):
intent = Intent(applicationContext, MyActivity::class.java).apply {
    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
}

val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(applicationContext, 0, intent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

notificationBuilder = notificationBuilder
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
...

Now I believe I have tried everything in my power for this new activity to trigger an animation:
(1) set animation via bundle with pending intent:
val animationBundle = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(
    this,
    R.anim.slide_in_right, // Animation for new activity entering
    R.anim.slide_out_left // Animation for current activity exiting
).toBundle()

val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, availabilityDealIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE, animationBundle)

(2) via onCreate of the new activity (works perfectly when I start the activity via startActivity, but not when I click the notification):
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE) {
    overrideActivityTransition(OVERRIDE_TRANSITION_OPEN, R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left, 0)
} else {
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left)
}

(3) via app theme animation (android:windowAnimationStyle):
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/LeftRightAnimation</item>

<resources>
    <style name="LeftRightAnimation" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
        <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">
            u/anim/slide_in_right
        </item>
        <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">
            u/anim/slide_out_left
        </item>
        <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">
            @anim/slide_in_left
        </item>
        <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">
            @anim/slide_out_right
        </item>
    </style>
</resources>

(4) via app theme transition:
<item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
<!-- specify enter and exit transitions -->
<item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@anim/slide_in_right</item>
<item name="android:windowExitTransition">@anim/slide_out_left</item>

Some additional information:

no launch mode set in Manifest
doesn't matter which activity is currently active while I click the notification, animation never happens
doesn't matter whether the app is in foreground or background while clicking the notification
onCreate() of the new activity gets only called once
animations work perfectly fine in every other case

I'm at the point of giving up.
